# JSF pages from entity classes generated code

Tags: java, jsf, netbeans

In NetBeans 7.4, their is an option while working with hibernate and JSF in project menu as -"JSF pages from entity classes". I selected an entity class and then it generated many packages and many class files. What are these exactly and what this files do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are these exactly and what this files do?

They are session scoped controller classes and some basic EJBs. They will allow you to ***access*** and ***persist*** entities object-data from and into your database. You don't need those generic controllers if you have entities classes , EJBs and managed 'backing' beans.

They are the '**C**' in the **MVC** (Model View Controller) user interface paradigm. 'V' is your Facelet (.xhtml, .jsf page). 'M' is the entity class.